# Pass through incoming claims

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

Is it possible to send a SAML claim *to* ADFS and then have ADFS use values from that incoming claim to generate its own?

Basically, we need to send a) information about the user (fairly straightforward), and b) information about the target (the question at hand).  The target is chosen by the user at time of SSO.

I've had it suggested to me to store the dynamic data in a database and then pull it in ADFS, but that runs the risk of creating issues if a user tries to open two targets in two windows at the same time.

**EDIT**:  When a user SSOs into the target application, they will be taken to a screen that shows information about a specific item.  We need to provide which item the user will need to see - and that will be selected by the user in the source application.

Essentially, user goes to Site A, clicks on Item 2, which SSOs them into Site B with Item 2 in context.  If the user selects Item 7 instead, they SSO into Site B with Item 7 in context.  This information isn't tied to the *user* because the user can access any of the items, but it needs to be provided in the SAML token to Site B.

Comment: Yes it is possible via claims rules at ad fs side. If you give more details we can show how. Advanced scenarios may require writing code for an attribute store to integrate with ad fs.

Comment: @maweeras:  I'd be happy to provide more details, if I knew what you needed to know.  Are there specific questions that I can answer?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your scenario with exactly what you want to do. What does target chosen by the user at time of SSO mean? And what is "information about target". What is your envisaged flow and end outcome?. Basically the more details you give the better.

Comment: @maweeras:  I've added some more explanation; let me know if that answers the questions.

Comment: This is not what I originally understood to be the ask. You seem to want to send some info to AD FS (not a SAML token but something akin to a query string parameter or something else in a POST body) which would influence the token issued by AD FS. AD FS has the ability to issue claims based on certain rules including incoming claims from another STS. But that's not quite what you describe.

Comment: @maweeras:  Right; I want Site A to tell ADFS what to issue.  Do you think this is possible?

Comment: No I don't see how you'd do this at ad fs side.

Comment: @maweeras:  Thanks!  That's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all "maweeras" is very authorative. You can trust has answer/comment to be correct :-).

As maweeras said: To get it into the SAML Token you have to use "claims rules". The trouble is getting it into the input set of the claimrules. That can either be something from: a. specific to the user (you said you don't want that, multiple windows could be fixed, but it is awful indeed), b. another SAML Token Issuer, or c. from some very specific HTTP headers.

As you specify it, only option c. remains. Already being tough, I must warn you to be extremely cautious because all of them already may have specific consequences. Some people would say that you are abusing them. Shooting yourself in the foot.

Not an answer, but a tip. You do not specify why you want it in the SAML token. If possible I would try to put it in a query parameter of a redirect from app A to app B. That will be preserved in the wctx (if authentications kicks in). You may already have to add several other things there to make sure the user will get the correct SSO (IdP, authnlevel etc.). If you need it signed, then sign it before you stuff it in the redirect?